# React-Select multivalue does not populate selected items like in example

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to use react-select (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) in my application, I have a select box whose options are loaded dynamically (i.e. I make a call to backend to fetch data). Right now I can see all the options populated in my dropdown, however when I click on any item onChange() event works but the element is not de-populated from the dropdown and shown at the top like a tag as shown in the official example. My select box:

```
<Select
    multi={true}
    name="form-field-name"
    options={this.props.metadata ? this.props.metadata["latest"].languages : []}
    labelKey="display_name"
    valueKey="id"
    onChange={this.addLanguage}
    clearable={false}
    value="id"
/>
```

This shows me on UI:

[image]

Here I have already selected two elements from the list but they are not shown on the top like following example:

[image]

I have imported js and css in my component as following:

```
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
```

**UPDATE**

When added multiple items:
[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No there are no errors

Comment: can this be fetch by npm dependency. (multiselect library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because you set the field `value="id"` In official documentation `value` field is defined as `initial field value`

So basically, in your snippet a static value is initially assigned and not getting any updates as you select more results.

In author's [example](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/Multiselect.js) code, multi select component is used like the following:

```
<Select 
  multi 
  simpleValue 
  disabled={this.state.disabled} 
  value={this.state.value} 
  placeholder="Select your favourite(s)" 
  options={this.state.options} 
  onChange={this.handleSelectChange} />
```

So whenever there is a change, `onChange` event uses `handleSelectChange` method.

`handleSelectChange (value) {
    console.log('You\'ve selected:', value);
    this.setState({ value });
    },`

This method then updates `this.state.value` which is used to display the selected values of component.

I don't know what your `this.addLanguage` method currently does, but if we take author's example as a baseline, what you need to to is instead of `value="id"` you should update it as `value={this.state.value}` and with your `this.addLanguage` method, you should update the value of `this.state.value`

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thanks for pointing out. Only one thing is not clear to me: if in my state I have say languages array in which I add languages from this select box, and then I use like :                                             value={this.state.languages}, it populates only first element at the top for each selection and not individual elements

Comment: Do you mean when you Select, let's say 'Arabic' 'German' and 'English' it only shows 'Arabic' ?

Comment: That's correct, also, clicking on cross icon throws error as it is nowhere defined what should happen. I am not sure if the component provides any function for it

Comment: Can you share the result of your this.state.value when you select more than one option ?

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot: in dev console you can see that the array holds two same elements and on UI you see same element populated twice

Comment: Can you try to add `simpleValue` props to your Select component, because in the documentation it says "The onChange event provides an array of selected options or a comma-separated string of values (eg "1,2,3") if simpleValue is true" so it might help maybe ? Because it seems like updating state is sort of problematic

Comment: Sure! i will try that